# Could we create a rating system for privacy?

Tags: privacy

I don't know whether something like this exists but I think it would be really useful if a privacy rating system would be established across all websites and apps.

An example would be something like ratings in movies: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Association_of_America_film_rating_system

Example of privacy systems:
PR - Privacy risky - this website gets access to your identity, your others tabs and keep track.

Answer (score 5):

Privacy is far more nuanced than that and the systems involved are extremely complex and layered and constantly changing. A single rating will not work to encapsulate all that. A movie is a closed piece of content that doesn't change.

Privacy regulations include the requirement for systems to describe what information is collected and what is done with it. That Privacy Notice becomes the "rating system" you describe.

Comment: You would get a quick idea how much does a site respect your privacy. That would be much easier to understand for the average user than to read the privacy notice.

Comment: It all depends on how the Privacy Notice is written. What you seem to be asking for is clarity, not a rating system. That's a different problem. A rating system is applied by a 3rd party after an assessment against criteria.

Comment: If all you want is clarity, then demand it as a customer. Privacy regulations also usually include that the notice to users be clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DuckDckGo's browser extension and mobile app will show you a Privacy Grade rating (A-F).  Their Privacy Grade is based on the prevalence of hidden trackers, encryption availability, and the quality of its privacy policy.  The exact scoring metrics do not seem be published.

It works with Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

[image]

Another organization, [Terms of Service; Didn't Read (todsr.org)](https://tosdr.org/index.html#services) is manually ranking web sites terms & services from class A (very good) to class E (very bad).  However, they have ranked only a few dozen sites thus far.

Comment: Can you expand on this? How is the grade determined? How does it work? I could create a grading system simply by randomly assigning grades.

Comment: @schroeder It looks pretty random if Facebook is getting a C+.

Comment: DuckDuckGo states "The Privacy Grade is scored automatically based on the prevalence of hidden tracker networks, encryption availability, and website privacy practices."  The details of the metrics are not described.  It would certainly be nice to have more transparency here on the ranking.  If you value DuckDuckGo's brand as a privacy advocate, you'll likely value the rankings also.